# How to insert the value of the foreign key from the primary key of another table in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, api, postman

In my Laravel project, I have created the cproduct table which has 3 foriegn keys. Now I need to add data to that table using postman. How can I do that.

c_products table I use,

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('c_products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('cproduct_id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('file_path');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->foreignId('category_id')->nullable()->constrained('p_categories');
        $table->foreignId('cactus_id')->nullable()->constrained('cacti');
        $table->foreignId('id')->nullable()->constrained('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

This is a code I have type so far in CProductController in order to add the data to table.

```
  <?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use App\Models\CProduct;
  class CProductController extends Controller
  {
   //
   function addCProduct(Request $req)
  {
    $cproduct=new CProduct;
    $cproduct->name=$req->input('name');
    $cproduct->price=$req->input('price');
    $cproduct->color=$req->input('color');
    $cproduct->file_path=$req->file('file')->store('c_product');
    $cproduct->save();
    return $cproduct;
  }
 }
```

For this "function addCProduct", I think the foreign key's fields need to be add to this. So, can I know the necessary code for this ?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: In your form, probably add a `<select name="category_id">` input with the categories  `<option value="{{ category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>`. Same for the cacti?

Comment: Then, what should I add for function addCProduct? Is that all I want to type that function?

Comment: You'd need to add `$cproduct->category_id=$req->input('category_id');` in your `addCProduct` function but that is assuming the form that is submitted has a `category_id` input value.  Same with cactus.

Answer (score 0):

In your form show categories as list

```
<select name="category_id">
  @foreach($categories as $category)
    <option value="{{ $category->id }}"> {{ $category->title }} </option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

Now in your controller get the category id like this

```
function addCProduct(Request $req)
  {
    $cproduct=new CProduct;
    $cproduct->category_id=$req->input('category_id');
    $cproduct->name=$req->input('name');
    $cproduct->price=$req->input('price');
    $cproduct->color=$req->input('color');
    $cproduct->file_path=$req->file('file')->store('c_product');
    $cproduct->save();
    return $cproduct;
  }
```

Comment: I am getting an error as "Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'}'}` or `&rbrace;`?", when I paste the code in my form in react.js. Since I am using react.js for the frontend.

Comment: The one I have shown is for blade, in react.js it won't work. You have to run loop on $categories and just print single values